# Is there a way I can set [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] for every action in a MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

I am setting it for every action on my controller. However is there some way I can do this globally for the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

The attribute works on controllers too.

You can even create a base controller and set the attribute on it (and therefore get the same authorization on all derived controllers)

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}

public class NewsController : BaseController 
{
}

public class ForumController : BaseController 
{
    [HttpPost, Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

**Update**

First question: You can put `[HandleError]` in your base controller to get MVC's error handling in all controllers. I've just written a [blog entry](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/) describing it.

Second question: Yes. Put the most specific `[Authorize]` attribute on the actions. (for instance authorize "users" in the base controller and "admins" on the Edit action).

Comment: I personally prefer having a base controller for this kind of stuffs. +1

Comment: What other things do you put in the base controller? Just wondering if I am missing out on a chance to make things even simpler.

Comment: Another related question. Let's say I do this at the controller class level. Then what about if I want to allow two roles such as "user" and "admin" to both access the same action. Can I override at the action level and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you mark a controller with the attribute, all action methods in the controller are restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you have to do is put that attribute at the top of the class where you makes it's declaration.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class TheController : Controller
```

When you do this, then every action on this controller will be checked for the admin role.